# Merge two identical git-svn branch HEADs without losing link with git-svn remote branch?

Tags: git, git-svn, git-merge

I've got a pair of git-svn branches which have been *manually* kept in sync by applying patches and what-not; `git-merge` has not been used. The branches are now in sync, which is to say that `git diff A B` has no output at all.

```
[A] +----+--+--+--+--------+---+--------+-+---+->
     \  /  X  /  /   \ \  X   /        / / \ X
[B] --+-----+---------+-+--+----------------+-+->
```

How can I get git to consider the two branches as merged, such that a future `git merge` will use today's HEAD as the merge-base, *without* losing the git-svn association to SVN?

### What I've tried

1. `git checkout A; git merge B`

   This selects the SVN branch point as the merge-base, and then attempts to resolve years of duplicated cross-merging that was done manually.

(This list expected to grow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about the impact on SVN, but `git checkout A; git merge --ours B` will record a merge B -> A where no changes are done at all, `--ours` means that the merge result is identical to the first parent.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. `git svn dcommit` does a rebase under the hood which breaks the merge, but this lets me re-connect two commits. Thanks!